# Lifetimes issues when placing a match with mutable references into a function

Tags: rust

Let's say I have this code (it's contrived, since it's heavily simplified):

```
enum Foo<'a, T> where T: 'a {
    Bar(&'a mut Vec<T>),
}

fn main() {
   let mut v = vec![1, 2];
   let foo: Foo<isize> = Foo::Bar(&mut v);
   let a = match foo {
       Foo::Bar(ref mut v) => &mut v[..],
   };
   a[1] = 10;
   println!("a = {:?}", a);
}
```

This works and everyone is happy. However, if I try to clean it up a bit by placing the match statement inside a function, I can't even get the function to compile, let alone put it to work for me. One of my many attempts looks like this:

```
fn unpack<'a, T>(foo: Foo<'a, T>) -> &'a mut [T] {
    match foo {
        Foo::Bar(ref mut v) => &mut v[..],
    } 
}
```

I just get the error:

```
error: `foo.0` does not live long enough
```

I have been trying to change to multiple lifetimes and adding a `where` clause (just like I had to do to get the Enum to work), but I can't seem to get it to work. My question is simply if it works (and how) or if the only option here is to use a macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foo::Bar(ref mut v)` borrows `&mut Vec<T>` from `foo` so it can't outlive foo (which only lives until the end of the function). What you actually want to do is take it (by value) so you should match on `Foo::Bar(v)`:

```
fn unpack<'a, T>(foo: Foo<'a, T>) -> &'a mut [T] {
    match foo {
        Foo::Bar(v) => &mut v[..],
    } 
}
```

Note: Rust will deref `v` as needed so the following will also work:

```
fn unpack<'a, T>(foo: Foo<'a, T>) -> &'a mut [T] {
    match foo {
        Foo::Bar(v) => v,
    } 
}
```